# Modified Java class (treated as binary files) immediately after git clone

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I've cloned a repo with git clone.

git status says that it's all up-to-date.

After that I open the folder with Eclipse and git status shows something different:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   bin/game/ClassName.class
    modified:   bin/game/ClassName1.class
    deleted:    bin/game/ClassName2.class

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

And git diff:

```
$ git diff
diff --git a/bin/game/ClassName.class b/bin/game/ClassName.class
index a501110..d891d9b 100644
Binary files a/bin/game/ClassName.class and b/bin/game/ClassName.class differ
diff --git a/bin/game/ClassName1.class b/bin/game/ClassName1.class
index bde5ba2..a8d76fe 100644
Binary files a/bin/game/ClassName1.class and b/bin/game/ClassName1.class differ
diff --git a/bin/game/ClassName2.class b/bin/game/ClassName2.class
deleted file mode 100644
index 08bec4e..0000000
Binary files a/bin/game/ClassName2.class and /dev/null differ
```

Why does git treat java class as binary files?
Any suggestion to solve this?

Comment: `.class` files have no o business being in the repository.

Comment: `.class` files ARE binary. (Hence the `bin` in the path) They are compiled classes from the `.java` files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git determines if some file is binary by checking a few things in the file's content.

These kind of files shouldn't probably be in your repo as they are `auto-generated` every time you compile your code.

You can safely delete them and add and entry in your `.gitignore` file with specifying `.class` files so that you cannot commit them again.

Answer (score -2):

You can directly go to your branch in Github, open your file which is changed to binary make a small change and commit. 
It may solve your problem.